# Why does 'a' represents outer in vim not 'o'?

Tags: vim

In vim, when you want to delete an inner word, you can press the following in the normal mode:

```
diw
```

but if you want to delete an outer word, you should press:

```
daw
```

now the question is, `i` represents `inner`, but why in the outer situation, it is not `dow` but `daw`?

Comment: It's not "outer", it's "around".

Comment: It's actually neither.

Comment: What is it @romainl?

Comment: @padawin, scroll down a bit.

Comment: ah gotcha, my bad. I also thought it was `around`, which I found it a good mnemonic.

Comment: "**a**round" certainly works well with "**a**" but it has the same problematic semantics as "outer".

Answer (score 6):

From `:help text-objects`:

> The commands that start with "a" select **"a"n object**
> including white space, the commands starting with "i" select an "inner" object
> without white space, or just the white space.  Thus the "inner" commands
> always select less text than the "a" commands.

Note that the boundaries of a text object are an integral part of the text object. If "inner" is what is *inside* those boundaries, then "outer" would be what is *outside* of them, thus everything else in the buffer.

From that point of view, selecting what is inside the boundaries *and* the boundaries themselves is really selecting "a" whole text objet.

```
Foo <span>bar</span> baz.
                           -- actual meaning --
    <---->   <----->       the boundaries of the text object
          <->              what is inside those boundaries
                             -> "inner text object"
                             -> "it"
    <-------------->       the boundaries + what is inside them
                             -> "a text object"
                             -> "at"

                           -- hypothetical meaning --
<-->                <--->  what is outside of the boundaries
                             -> "outer text object"
                             -> "ot"
```